# What is the recommended way to write a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I usually use following way to write my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MasterInsertUpdateDelete  
    (@id INTEGER,  
     @first_name VARCHAR(10),  
     @last_name VARCHAR(10),  
     @salary DECIMAL(10,2),  
     @city VARCHAR(20),  
     @StatementType NVARCHAR(20) = '')  
AS  
BEGIN  
    IF @StatementType = 'Insert'  
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO employee (id, first_name, last_name, salary, city) 
        VALUES (@id, @first_name, @last_name, @salary, @city)  
    END  

    IF @StatementType = 'Select'  
    BEGIN  
        SELECT * FROM employee  
    END  

    IF @StatementType = 'Update'  
    BEGIN  
        UPDATE employee 
        SET First_name = @first_name, 
            Last_name = @last_name, 
            salary = @salary,  
            city = @city  
        WHERE id = @id  
    END  
    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Delete'  
    BEGIN  
        DELETE FROM employee 
        WHERE id = @id  
    END  
END
```

The second way is to split the one stored procedure into 4 separate stored procedures for insert, delete, select and update the table.

Which one is recommended with respect to performance ?

Comment: All these depends on the complexity of the statement / operations. If your query is too long/complex for either select, insert, update or delete and also performing options based on that then you should write separate procedure otherwise it is ok for one procedures for all the operations. Remember use case and future update is also remembered.

Comment: Why did you use the word `else` only 1 time ? 

Comment: 4 is far more maintainable than 1 with multiple processes. Also, it means you don't have to have wasted parameters. As it stands you **must** pass a value for `@first_name`, `@last_name`, `@salary` and `@city`, even though you don't use them for your `DELETE`. You also must pass all of those parameters, and an `ID` for the `SELECT` even though you use none of them. Your `UPDATE`, as well effectively requires them all (including the existing value), even if you only want to update 1 column.

Comment: IMHO (the answer is opinion-based), a stored procedure should have a well-defined interface. The interface includes not only the parameters but the result sets, messages, etc. returned. The Swiss army knife interface violates this because result sets are returned, or not, depending in the parameter values passed. Think of all the unit test cases needed to thoroughly test the proc.

Comment: Based on the generally accepted **Single Responsibility Principle**, I would always opt for an **one stored procedure does *ONE* job only** approach. Do not try to does these "everything-but-the-kitchen-sink" approaches - they might *sound clever* at first - but long term, they're a lot more trouble than benefits....

Answer (score 2):

You are asking whether it is better to write a single stored procedure that does four things or a separate procedure for one thing.

At first I thought this was opinion-based and was going to close the question.  It might be opinion-based, but the evidence for four stored procedures seems pretty overwhelming.

1. A stored procedure should encapsulate logic that "goes together".  Your single procedure has multiple personality disorder (well, that name is no longer used but you get the idea).
2. You have declared a bunch of parameters.  Some personalities do not use them.  Others might have different meanings.
3. If you start writing tests for the stored procedure, you are quite likely to miss important chunks of functionality.
4. SQL Server stashes compile plans for stored procedures, generally on the first run.  You may not get the optimal execution plan for some of the branches.

I cannot think of a good defense of combining such different functionality into one procedure.

I would also add that I don't see much benefit to wrapping basic SQL functions in a stored procedure, unless you are auditing, validating the data, or using the stored procedures to control access.  I doubly don't see the benefit for `SELECT` statements.

Comment: *"or using the stored procedures to control access"* I find this is the most common reason. Seems silly for a `SELECT *` with no `WHERE`, but often user/service account are limited to only be able to `EXEC` SPs, so that they cannot interact directly with the underlying data. With things like GDPR now, this style of compartmentalising is really useful for limiting exposure. But, I completely agree with everything said here.

Answer (score 0):

I think if every operation is done in a separate stored procedure, it is better because it makes managing and updating the stored procedures easier.

**MasterInsert**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MasterInsert
    (@first_name VARCHAR(10),
     @last_name  VARCHAR(10),
     @salary     DECIMAL(10, 2),
     @city       VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO employee (id, first_name, last_name, salary, city)
    VALUES (@id, @first_name, @last_name, @salary, @city)
END
```

**MasterSelect**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MasterSelect
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM employee
END
```

**MasterUpdate**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MasterUpdate
    (@id         INTEGER,
     @first_name VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
     @last_name  VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
     @salary     DECIMAL(10, 2) = NULL,
     @city       VARCHAR(20) = NULL, )
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE employee
    SET    First_name = @first_name,
           last_name  = @last_name,
           salary     = @salary,
           city       = @city
    WHERE  id         = @id
END
```

**MasterDelete**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MasterDelete
     (@id INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE 
    FROM employee
    WHERE id = @id
END
```

**MasterInsertUpdateDelete**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MasterInsertUpdateDelete
     (@id            INTEGER = NULL,
      @first_name    VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
      @last_name     VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
      @salary        DECIMAL(10, 2) = NULL,
      @city          VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
      @StatementType NVARCHAR(20) = '')
AS
BEGIN
    IF @StatementType = 'Insert'
    BEGIN
        EXEC MasterInsert @first_name,
             @last_name,
             @salary,
             @city
    END
    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Select'
    BEGIN
        EXEC MasterSelect
    END
    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Update'
    BEGIN
        EXEC MasterUpdate @id,
             @first_name,
             @last_name,
             @salary,
             @city
    END
    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Delete'
    BEGIN
        EXEC MasterDelete @id
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my view write stored procedure as below.
Write comment on every section you don't need to separate the part.
Also mentioned the detail like who created and who modified the stored procedure and reason for changes. This may help you in future to track the information. And always use tab in place of space while you are writing Begin and End.

```
-- =============================================
-- Created By:      Author Name
-- Create Date: Create Date
-- Modify By with Reason: Name of Person who modified the Store Procedure, Description
-- =============================================

-- Drop Proc MasterInsertUpdateDelete  
-- Execute MasterInsertUpdateDelete 1,'First Name','Last Name',22500.15,'Banglore','Type'
Create PROCEDURE MasterInsertUpdateDelete  
(  
   @id INTEGER,  
   @first_name VARCHAR(10),  
   @last_name VARCHAR(10),  
   @salary DECIMAL(10,2),  
   @city VARCHAR(20),  
   @StatementType nvarchar(20) = ''  
)  

AS  
BEGIN  
    -- Insert Employee
    IF @StatementType = 'Insert'  
        BEGIN  
           insert into employee (id,first_name,last_name,salary,city) values( @id, @first_name, @last_name, 
           @salary, @city)  
        END  

    -- Select Employee
    IF @StatementType = 'Select'  
        BEGIN  
           select * from employee  
        END  

    -- Update Employee
    IF @StatementType = 'Update'  
        BEGIN  
           UPDATE employee SET  
              First_name = @first_name, last_name = @last_name, salary = @salary,  
              city = @city  
           WHERE id = @id  
        END  

    -- Delete Employee
    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Delete'  
        BEGIN  
           DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = @id  
        END  
END
```

Comment: What is your reason for wanting a `MasterInsertUpdateDelete` to begin with? Do you not agree it is more conventional to have different stored procedures for each of the CRUD operations? What value are you gaining by doing it this way?

Comment: I suggest leveraging source control to capture the commit history. That will track the author, reason for changes, revision history without embedding the info as comments in the source code.